# Jackson mapper Deserialization should fail when integer value given for string type

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I have a Sample class

```
data class Sample(
        var proxied: Boolean,
        var id: String,
        var interval: Int,
        var parameters: Map<String, String>,
)
```

below is Sample JSON

```
{
 "proxied": "abc",
 "id": 123,
 "interval": "test",
 "parameters": {
    "param1": 1,
    "param2": 2
  }
}
```

when I try to deserialize the JSON to Sample, it should throw deserialisation exception since I have given incompatible type values like for `id` I have give integer value `123` but it should be a string value.  It fails for types Int, Long but not for the String, Boolean, Map

Is there a better way to fail deserialization when json object does'nt map exactly with object fields type?

Comment: This is a Kotlin class, why is java tagged?

Comment: thanks, tagged to Kotlin